# Ccraping with rvest - search by div id

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am new to scraping and I am trying to extract information by car on the site:
https://www.plugndrive.ca/electric-cars-available-in-canada/

```
library(rvest);library(tidyverse)

elec_url <- read_html('https://www.plugndrive.ca/electric-cars-available-in-canada/')

car_list <- elec_url %>% html_nodes('.car-title') %>% html_text() %>% tolower() %>% 
    gsub(' ','-',.)

price <- read_html(paste0('https://www.plugndrive.ca/pnd_evcar_cat/',car_list[[1]],'/')) %>% 
    html_nodes('.starting-price .value') %>% html_text() %>% sub("\\..*", "", .) %>% gsub('^\\$|\\,','',.) %>% 
    as.numeric()
```

How would I go about scraping the range from either the range from the Electric Range id

```
(XPath = //*[@id="content"]/section[1]/div[2]/p[2]/strong/span)
```

to get 42 km.

Or the range on electric id in the Performance tab near the bottom

`(XPath = //*[@id="performance-container"]/ul/li[3]/span[2]/text())`

to get 35 km (don't ask me why the ranges aren't equal!)

I get the following error when trying to just basically run:

```
read_html(paste0('https://www.plugndrive.ca/pnd_evcar_cat/',car_list[[1]],'/')) %>% 
html_nodes('//*[@id="performance-container"]/ul/li[3]/span[2]/text()') %>% html_text()
```

> Error in tokenize(css) : Unexpected character '/' found at position 1

Comment: The default selector type for `html_modes` is a CSS selector and you seem to be using an xpath selector. You should be calling `html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="performance-container"]/ul/li[3]/span[2]/text()')` (with the named parameter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the price by using :

```
library(rvest)

price <- elec_url %>% 
          html_nodes('div.inner p.price-container span.starting-price') %>%
          html_text()

price
# [1] "$32,930"  "$32,990"  "$33,749"  "$33,965"  "$37,895"  "$39,990" 
# [7] "$41,499"  "$42,495"  "$42,595"  "$42,760"  "$43,998"  "$44,590" 
#[13] "$44,898"  "$44,950"  "$44,995"  "$44,998"  "$44,999"  "$45,371" 
#[19] "$55,990"  "$56,469"  "$66,400"  "$68,550"  "$69,400"  "$69,900" 
#[25] "$72,200"  "$72,390"  "$74,950"  "$74,950"  "$80,500"  "$89,800" 
#[31] "$90,000"  "$109,090" "$116,090" "$122,800" "$149,900" "$173,900"
```

If you want to convert this to number you can use `parse_number` from `readr` :

```
readr::parse_number(price)
# [1]  32930  32990  33749  33965  37895  39990  41499  42495  42595  42760
#[11]  43998  44590  44898  44950  44995  44998  44999  45371  55990  56469
#[21]  66400  68550  69400  69900  72200  72390  74950  74950  80500  89800
#[31]  90000 109090 116090 122800 149900 173900
```

---

**EDIT**

Maybe I previously missed what you were looking for, if you want to get Electric Range and Gasoline Range from each of the individual car page. You could first extract all the URL's and then then get the numbers from it.

```
library(tidyverse)

all_urls <- elec_url %>% html_nodes('div.evCar a') %>%  html_attr('href')

all_ranges <- map_chr(all_urls, ~.x %>% 
                      read_html() %>% html_nodes('div.info p strong') %>%
                      .[1] %>% html_text())

tibble(all_ranges, car_list) %>%
  mutate(electic_range = str_extract(all_ranges, '(?<=Electric Range:\\s)\\d+'), 
         gasoline_range = str_extract(all_ranges,'(?<=Gasoline Range:\\s)\\d+')) %>%
  select(-all_ranges)

# A tibble: 36 x 3
#   car_list               electic_range gasoline_range
#   <chr>                  <chr>         <chr>         
# 1 ford-fusion-energi     42            940           
# 2 toyota-prius-prime     40            995           
# 3 hyundai-ioniq-phev     47            961           
# 4 kia-niro-phev          42            853           
# 5 volkswagen-e-golf      198           NA            
# 6 mini-cooper-se         177           NA            
# 7 hyundai-ioniq-electric 274           NA            
# 8 subaru-crosstrek-phev  27            747           
# 9 kia-soul-electric      383           NA            
#10 honda-clarity-phev     77            475           
# … with 26 more rows
```